# After integration of Kafka in reactjs ,some issue's happening

Tags: reactjs, apache-kafka, react-redux

After integration of Kafka in reactjs, some issue's happening as follow.

```
kafkaClient.js:728 Uncaught TypeError: net.createConnection is not a function
    at KafkaClient.push../node_modules/kafka-node/lib/kafkaClient.js.KafkaClient.createBroker (kafkaClient.js:728)
    at KafkaClient.push../node_modules/kafka-node/lib/kafkaClient.js.KafkaClient.setupBroker (kafkaClient.js:314)
    at KafkaClient.push../node_modules/kafka-node/lib/kafkaClient.js.KafkaClient.connectToBroker (kafkaClient.js:253)
    at kafkaClient.js:198
    at Object.doWhilst (async.js:3149)
    at KafkaClient.push../node_modules/kafka-node/lib/kafkaClient.js.KafkaClient.connectToBrokers (kafkaClient.js:197)
    at kafkaClient.js:155
    at async.js:4041
    at replenish (async.js:1041)
    at async.js:1047
    at eachOfLimit (async.js:1073)
    at async.js:1078
    at _parallel (async.js:4040)
    at Object.series (async.js:4917)
    at RetryOperation._fn (kafkaClient.js:154)
    at RetryOperation.push../node_modules/retry/lib/retry_operation.js.RetryOperation.attempt (retry_operation.js:104)
    at KafkaClient.push../node_modules/kafka-node/lib/kafkaClient.js.KafkaClient.connect (kafkaClient.js:146)
    at new KafkaClient (kafkaClient.js:100)
    at Module.<anonymous> (MessageList.js:16)
    at Module../src/components/MessageList.js (MessageList.js:188)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782)
    at fn (bootstrap:150)
    at Module../src/App.js (App.css?da7c:45)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782)
    at fn (bootstrap:150)
    at Module../src/index.js (index.css?02e3:45)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782)
    at fn (bootstrap:150)
    at Object.0 (Request.js:37)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:782)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
    at main.chunk.js:1
```

Please help on this, how to resolve the kafka-node issue's in reactjs?

Comment: kafka server-side, react client-side

Comment: `kafka-node` is meant to be running by a NodeJS server. React doesn't require Node, therefore is not meant to use server-side frameworks