# How to fetch data from Kafka in NodeJS

Tags: sql, node.js, database, express, apache-kafka

Currently I am trying to implement `Kafka` in `Node.js`. My whole project structure is a react front-end connecting to a `Node.js` server. While I am have a python based platform for storing `sql` and fetching data from database. So, I am trying to use `Kafka` to do the communication between `Node.js server` <-> `Python Platform`.

I can able to create the simple API in `Express` and push the data into Kafka(producer) and then trigger some "Fetch Data Class" in my Python Platform. However, now I stuck with getting the data and shown them in my `React` front-end. I have no much idea about how to return the data from Python plarform <=> `Kafka consumer` in `Node.js` and also my `Kafka consumer` in `Node.js` <=> `Express`. Please kindly help me out  about the how to get the data from `consumer` by `Express`? Thanks!

React.js:

```
let url = "localhost/GetData"
axios
    .post(url,params)
    .then(function(response){
    if(response.data.data.length !== 0) {
        'do something
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
    })
```

Node.js - server.js:

```
router.post('/GetData', (req, res) => {
    getConnection(function(err, conn){
        if (err) {
            return res.json({ success: false, error: err })
        } else {
            let getData = new getDataObject(id, price, fruit);
            let getDataReq = Object.assign({}, producerRequest);
            let payloads = [];
            getDataReq .messages = [];
            getDataReq .messages.push(JSON.stringify(t.get()));
            payloads.push(getDataReq );
            
            kafkaProducer.send(payloads, function(err, result){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err)
                    return res.json({ success: false, error: err });
                }else{
                    console.log(result)
                    return res.json({ success: true, data: result });
                }
            })          
        }
    });
})
```

Node.js - kafkaproduced.js:

```
const kafka = require('kafka-node');
const { NODE_ENV } = require('../../config/env');
const config = require('../../config/kafka.json');
const logger = require('../logger')

const kafkaProducerConfig = '11.11.11.11'; -fake address
const {producer_kafka_server} = kafkaProducerConfig;
const producer_client = new kafka.KafkaClient({kafkaHost: producer_kafka_server});
const producer = new kafka.Producer(producer_client);

producer.on('ready', function(){
    logger.info('kafka producer is ready...')
})

producer.on('error', function(err){
    logger.error(err)
});

exports.producerRequest = {topic: 'get_database_data', messages:[], timestamp: Date.now()};

exports.kafkaProducer = producer;
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/55749715/163072

Comment: @influent Thanks for your answer, but how to communicate between React and kafka consumer in node js?

Comment: Hi @WILLIAM, do you want to pass realtime data as its arrives to react application or just want show available data at time of page loading?

Comment: Hi @VishalPawar, it don't have to be realtime. I want to pre-load some data at the beginning and get the data back after user post request i.e. after click the search button

Comment: If you want show the whole data of topic first you need to store data somewhere else like database or in memory because on every request kafka consumer will not read from starting and if you want this you to start new consumer each time. This will be not feasible approach instead it you can use realtime db for such operation.